# Isolating a variable under square root

Tags: quadratics, rational-functions

Given this equation:

$T=\sqrt{(ugx)^2+(T_0)^2}$

You're asked to isolate $x$. My process was:

$T=ugx + T_0$ (the square root cancelled the exponents)

$T-T_0=ugx$

$x=\frac{T-T_0}{ug}$

But that was the wrong answer, and they instead followed this process:

$T^2=(\sqrt{(ugx)^2+(T_0)^2})^2$ (squaring both sides)

$T^2-(T_0)^2=(ugx)^2$

$\pm \sqrt{T^2-(T_0)^2}=\sqrt{(ugx)^2}$

$\pm \sqrt{T^2-(T_0)^2}=ugx$ (why no $\pm$ with $ugx$?)

$x=\frac{\pm \sqrt{T^2-(T_0)^2}}{ug}$

The answer further said that only positive solutions are included, so the final answer is

$x=\frac{\sqrt{T^2-(T_0)^2}}{ug}$

Doesn't that line also evaluate to

$x=\frac{T-T_0}{ug}$? I'm pretty confused.

Comment: It is *not* true that $\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$ evaluates to $x-y$. That may be what is confusing you. If you had $\sqrt{(x-y)^2}$ then that would evaluate to $|x-y|$, but $x^2-y^2$ is not the same as $(x-y)^2$. Instead, you have that $(x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2-2xy$.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right @Eff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$\sqrt{2^2-1^2}\ne 2-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Squaring we get
$$T^2-T_0^2=(ugx)^2$$ so we obtain 
$$ugx=\pm\sqrt{T^2-T_0^2}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Why is there no $\pm$ after taking the square root of $ugx$?

Comment: Do you mean NO $$\pm$$? I have written this!

Comment: I meant, you went from $(ugx)^2$ to $ugx$, why not $\pm\sqrt{ugx}$?

Comment: May be i've been awake too long, lol.

Comment: Ok, we have $$\sqrt{(ugx)^2}=\pm ugx$$ i have written this  before the square root on the right-hand side.

Comment: it doesn't matter at all